# How to order an instance with MongoDB installed

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am working with Softlayer Python Client API. I would like to laucn an instance with mongodb installed via API.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order a virtual guest with a Mongo DB it’s necessary to use the price id of this item.
The best way to verify/place an order with the available price items for any product is to review the next method:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices

The next script can be used to order a Virtual Guest with MongoDB Community Edition.

```
"""
Order Virtual Guest with MongoDB Community Edition.

Important manual pages:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

order = {
    'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest',
    'quantity': 1,
    'virtualGuests': [
        {'hostname': 'test-template', 'domain': 'example.com'}
    ],
    'location': 168642,  # San Jose 1
    'packageId': 46,     # CCI Package
    'prices': [
        {'id': 1640},  # 1 x 2.0 GHz Core
        {'id': 1644},  # 1 GB RAM
        {'id':  905},  # Reboot / Remote Console
        {'id':  272},  # 10 Mbps Public & Private Networks
        {'id':50231},  # 1000 GB Bandwidth
        {'id':   21},  # 1 IP Address
        {'id': 2202},  # 25 GB (SAN)
        {'id':13945},  # CentOS 6.x - Minimal Install (64 bit)
        {'id':   55},  # Host Ping Monitoring
        {'id':   57},  # Email and Ticket Notifications
        {'id':   58},  # Automated Notification Response
        {'id':  420},  # Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account
        {'id':  418},  # Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting
       {'id':20893}   # MongoDB Community Edition
    ]
}

try:
       # Replace verifyOrder for placeOrder
       result = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].verifyOrder(order)
       pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
       pp('Unable to verify/place order faultCode=%s, faultString=%s' 
       % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

You could review the next link for further information as well:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3

> UPDATE

An object mask would be the best way to retrieve additional object's data, like the item price ids of an instance already created.

You can use this mask:

```
mask[billingItem[orderItem,children[orderItem]]]
```

Or this one, which is more granular:

```
mask[billingItem[id,orderItem[itemPriceId],children[id,orderItem[itemPriceId]]]]
```

In python you could use these masks in this way:

```
"""
Get Virtual Guest and its itme price ids

Important manual pages:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getObject
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

virtualGuestId = 25129311

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

objectMask = 'mask[billingItem[id,orderItem[itemPriceId],children[id,orderItem[itemPriceId]]]]'

try:
    result = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].getObject(id=virtualGuestId, mask=objectMask)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    pp('Unable to get virtual guest faultCode=%s, faultString=%s' 
    % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Regarding the ssh keys, you just need to add this line into the **order** object of the above script (the one to order a virtual guest with mongo db)

```
'sshKeys': [{'sshKeyIds': [214147, 94206]}]
```

Comment: Thanks. The code snippet was very helpful. How do I get the price ids of an instance already provisioned?

Comment: I took twicked your code snippet to fit my settings. But, whatever I have checked, I can't figure out the right syntax for adding ssh keys. Here is my last attempt:

Comment: order = {
             'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest',
             'useHourlyPricing': True,
             'quantity': 1,
             'sshKeys': [{ 'sshKeyIds': [716119] }],
             'virtualGuests': [{'hostname': set me, 
                                'domain': set me',
                                'sshKeyCount': 1,
                                'sshKeys': [716119]
                                }],
.....}

Comment: I updated my answer with the points of your last requirements.